# On os x mountain lion, how can i remove an entry from the "routing table"?

Tags: macos, networking, internet

So today I was trying to reach a website who's IP happened to start with "5", however I couldn't do anything besides resolve the IP, not even ping it. So I did some googling and google said that I should run a command:

```
Adrians-MacBook-Pro:~ Adrian$ netstat -rn -finet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.0.1.1           UGSc           25        0     en1
5                  link#8             UC              1        0    ham0
10.0.1/24          link#5             UCS             2        0     en1
10.0.1.1           78:ca:39:f9:af:80  UHLWIir        27      245     en1   1160
10.0.1.5           127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
10.0.1.14          0:13:d4:36:ff:36   UHLWIi          0        0     en1   1055
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1       14     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
```

I assume that the line starting with a "5" is messing my internet up. How can I remove this entry?

Bonus points to you if you have any idea how it got there in the first place.

Comment: The Netif of ham0 appears to be hamachi / LogMeIn which creates VPN tunnels.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [Hamachi Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29#Addressing) describes the problem now that 5.x addresses are being given out by ripe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VPN software Hamachi uses 5.x addresses that it has no ownership of. Wasn't a problem until the 5.x block was assigned to a regional internet registry and parts of it started to be given out. Without getting into complex solutions your choices are:

- Remove the Hamachi VPN software
- Turn off the Hamachi software when you need to access real 5.x addresses
- Accept that you can't access real 5.x internet addresses due Hamachi currently using them for tunnel addresses

References: Wikipedia article on [Hamachi Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29#Addressing)